# PHP remove entry if array value equals to 0

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is what i get when i print_r my array. it's a multi-dimensional array which contains the following values.

```
    [7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 34
        [2] => 181
        [3] => 50
    )



    [9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 47
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1621
        [3] => 45
    )
   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 120
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 121
        [3] => 45
    )
```

I would like to remove all entries in which the key [1] equals to 0. After doing the modifications, My final array should like this

```
    [7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 34
        [2] => 181
        [3] => 50
    )



[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 47
    )
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach` to the rescue:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $entry) {
    if(isset($entry[1]) && $entry[1] === 0) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

And an [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/array_filter) example:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($entry) {
    return $entry[1] !== 0;
});
```

(assumes at least php 5.3, though you can get around that by creating a named function and passing that as the second parameter to `array_filter`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only remove array with value 0 whatever the key, you can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter) .

```
    <?php

    $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,0,'',null);

    print_r(array_filter($array));
    ?>
```

Output :

```
    Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove empty,null and 0 value from array using this code

Code:-

```
$array = array('one', 'two', '', 'three', null,'four','0');

$filteredarray = array_values( array_filter($array) );

print_r($filteredarray);
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
)
```

Thank You!!   All The Best!!