# Filter multi array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

i want to filter this array and get all arrays where [1] => 1. So the php code must return Array [1], [2] and [4]. I have no idea how to do it, so I will be grateful for any help.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => data1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => data2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => data3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2
            [2] => data4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] => data5
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 3
            [2] => data6
        )
)
```

Comment: You can use `array_filter()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP remove entry if array value equals to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388469/php-remove-entry-if-array-value-equals-to-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple foreach loop and appending to a new array when the item matches as required will work:

```
$in = [
    [1,1,'data1'],
    [2,1,'data2'],
    [3,2,'data3'],
    [4,2,'data4'],
    [5,1,'data5'],
    [6,3,'data6'],
];

$out = [];
foreach ($in as $arr) {
    if ($arr[1] == 1) {
        $out[] = $arr;
    }
}

var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parent array was called $master:

```
foreach ($master as $m)
{
  if ($m[1] != 1)
  {
    unset($m);
  }
}

return $master;
```